# Android: How to cancel/interrupt a synchronous Service call?

Tags: android, android-service, request-cancelling

For the Application object, I call `bindService()`. The `onServiceConnected()` callback receives an `IBinder` object, and I hand that to an `AsyncTask`.

There, I get my service object by calling `ServiceClass.Stub.asInterface(iBinderObject)` and call some method using this **service object**.

It's a **synchronous method** and I **cannot influence the service's timeout setting** (and who knows whether its timeout implementation is reliable). So, beforehand, I `postDelayed()` my own timeout handler on a separate thread.

The timeout code calls `unbindService()` to unbind the Application from the service and yields a timeout result.

I haven't found a way to interrupt the service call if the timeout runs first. The `unbindService()` has no visible effect wrt this. Calling `AsyncTask.cancel(true)` changes nothing, either. The `IBinder` object does not seem to provide any obvious method which could be of any help.

What I observe is that the `AsyncTask` keeps waiting for the service call to return, which can delay the start of the next `AsyncTask` significantly with the standard `Executor`.

Any experiences? Ideas?

Comment: Did you have any Check inside your AsyncTask that keeps an eye on whether it is cancelled using AsyncTask.isCancelled(). If you use that , you can simply finish your AsyncTask,

Comment: @GauravArora Thank you for your comment. As I said, I want to interrupt a synchronous service call, the code of which I cannot influence.

Comment: As a general rule, Synchronous calls can not be cancelled. That's why they are Synchronous. But you can possibly try stopping the service after your timeout handler kicks in.

Comment: @GauravArora Thanks for your promising suggestion to try and stop the service after unbindig it in the timeout handler. It doesn't change a thing, presumably due to the method call being processed. Of course, it wouldn't work anyway if another app has bound to the service. But it would have been valuable still. -- Binding to a service and calling a service method involves a binder thread and interprocess communication, so in my view, there was a certain probability that interrupting the call might work. Despite the reference claiming that `DeadObjectException` is the only exception thrown.

Comment: ...so, looking at a couple of API references, it seems the only destructive Android way to end something is to kill a process. In other words, the only ways to avoid AsyncTask jams due to unresponsive services (if the app were to continue) would be to either use `THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR` for the AsyncTasks or create minimal threads (referencing as few resources as possible) for the service calls, such that those can wait a long time for the result without causing too much harm?

Comment: Probably last option from my side, stopService() should give you a call in Service.onDestroy(). Can you set a flag inside onDestroy() and stop whatever synchronous process is happening inside Service?

Comment: @GauravArora Thank you for not giving up on this easily. Unfortunately, I forgot to mention explicitly that the service is not "mine" (hence the fact that I cannot control its timeout setting). So I can't change its code. -- I think I will isolate critical service calls in detachable Threads and live with their potential zombiefication... Thanks again.

Comment: Alright, In that case, the only option for you is to have a error-resilient AsyncTask/Thread handling all the Service Interaction and keep it safe from any anomalies from the service.

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted, a synchronous call cannot be interrupted.

If this is a concern, and you have any input in the design of the service API, you can perform asynchronous operations using a pair of one-way AIDL interfaces, like this:

```
package sample;
oneway interface IServer {
    void doWork(IClient cb);
}
```

and

```
package sample;
oneway interface IClient {
    void reportResult(String result);
}
```